# Why is there white space inside ellipse from matplotlib.patches.ellipse?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a small ellipse, but there is white space inside it. There was no such problem with greater values for width and length though. The code is as follows:

```
w = 1
l = 3

xy_e = np.zeros((181,2))
a_e = np.arange(1,181,2)

for i in range(90):
   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   fig.set_size_inches(0.256, 0.256)

   xy_e[i] = xy_gen()

   e = patches.Ellipse((xy_e[i,0], xy_e[i,1]), w, l, color = 'black', angle = a_e[i])

   plt.xticks(np.arange(0,256,30))
   plt.yticks(np.arange(0,256,30))

   ax.add_patch(e)

   x = '...'
   y = '.png'

   fig.savefig(x + str(a_e[i]) + y,  dpi = 1000)
```

The results are as follows:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdZkn.png)

Comment: where does `xy_gen` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Reduced your code a bit to this but the ellipse comes out fine:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(0.256, 0.256)

ax.set_xlim(0, 10); ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

w = 1; l = 3
e = Ellipse((5, 5), w, l, color = 'black', angle=45)

ax.add_patch(e)

fig.savefig("tmp.png",  dpi = 1000)
```

[image]